# For perfromance - While Loop or Row_Number should be used to update a dataset?

Tags: sql-server

Can someone explain if a While Loop with a RowCounter is faster or slower than using ROW_NUMBER in SQL server?

Or is there no difference?

The existing stored procedure is too complex to put it all in a View and is very slow.. this is the While Loop, but how could it be done with ROW_NUMBER in Sql Server 2008 R2, and would there be any performance benefit?

```
DECLARE @StopRow AS INT

SELECT @StopRow = MAX(RowID)
FROM #Temp1

DECLARE @RowCounter AS INT

SET @RowCounter = 1

DECLARE @colID INT

WHILE (@RowCounter <= @StopRow)
BEGIN
    SELECT @colID = colID
    FROM #Temp1
    WHERE colRowID = @RowCounter

    IF (
            EXISTS (
                SELECT ParentColID
                FROM ParentTable a WITH (NOLOCK)
                JOIN MoreTableData b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.priID = b.priID
                    AND colID = @colID
                WHERE anotherID NOT IN (
                        SELECT anotherID
                        FROM @anotherTempTable
                        )
                )
            )
        UPDATE #Temp1
        SET aFlag = 0
        WHERE colRowID = @RowCounter

    SET @RowCounter = @RowCounter + 1
END
```

Found this StackOverflow now that I understand the SET based (UPDATE) verbage ..
[How to convert a loop in SQL to Set-based logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365029/how-to-convert-a-loop-in-sql-to-set-based-logic)

Comment: Doing things row by row is one of the most expensive ways to go about this.  Take advantage of SQL's set based optimizations and try to rewrite this without a loop.

Comment: Please do not write RBAR code (row by agonizing row).  99.99% of the time, there is a "set based" way to do what you want.

Comment: TY - while I am coming in to optimize after-the-fact - I still have much to learn about doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, a set-based solution offers a better performance than a cursor based solution.

If performance is a concern, I would try to rewrite my solution using a set based solution thus:

```
UPDATE  t1
SET     aFlag = 0
FROM    #Temp1 t1
WHERE   colRowID BETWEEN 1 AND (SELECT MAX(RowID) FROM #Temp1)
AND     EXISTS 
(
    SELECT ParentColID
        FROM ParentTable a 
        JOIN MoreTableData b ON a.priID = b.priID
        AND colID = t1.colID
        WHERE anotherID NOT IN 
        (
            SELECT anotherID
            FROM   @anotherTempTable
        )
)
```

Then, on a dev/server server I would use a SQL Trace / Extended events session to track following main KPIs: Duration, CPU, [Logical] Reads and I would compare these two solutions (cursor based vs. set based).

Note #1: `(SELECT MAX(RowID) FROM #Temp1)` sub-query should be evaluated just one time because it isn't correlated sub-query.

Note #2: Try to replace NOT IN with NOT EXISTS. [Reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231171/how-to-determine-which-foos-have-no-associated-bars/19231673#19231673).

Comment: an amazing return. original query was 25 seconds and now returning in 7 seconds. That is 18 seconds faster!

Answer (score 2):

why u nead any loop? Can't u do in one `UPDATE` ?

```
   UPDATE T
        SET aFlag = 0       
   FROM #Temp1 AS T       
   WHERE EXISTS (
                SELECT ParentColID
                FROM ParentTable a WITH (NOLOCK)
                JOIN MoreTableData b WITH (NOLOCK) 
                    ON a.priID = b.priID
                    AND a.colID = t.colID
                WHERE anotherID NOT IN (
                        SELECT anotherID
                        FROM @anotherTempTable
                        )
                )
```

Not tested.